# Enumerated array in C

Tags: c, arrays, enums

I need to make an array work like an enum, where I can change the index position of an element in the array during initialization. For example, we can have an enum

```
enum Fruit_t {
APPLES,
ORANGES,
STRAWBERRIES = 8 }
```

Here, strawberries instead of 2, becomes 8. Can this be done in an array instead, where the position can be changed? Is this possible in C? if yes, please how?

Any other possible suggestion will be appreciated

LET ME EXPLAIN MY INTENTIONS

I am using a an array of function pointers

```
static BT (*data_access_typ [4])() =
{ 

    NULL,
    ARRAY,  
    STRUCT,
    dnt_cr

};
```

I will need to call this function

```
(access_data[*VAL])()
```

Where *VAL can be any of this values in this enum

```
enum data_access_typ    {
                        Null, array, struc, bool, bit_str, int32, unsin32, float_pt, oct_str=9, vis_str,
                        bcd=13, int8=15, int16, unsin8, unsin16, int64=20, unsin64, _enum, float32, float64,
                        date_tim, date, time, dnt_cr=225
                    };
```

There are separate functions to perform if the values is either NULL, ARRAY, STRUCT, up till dnt_car (255) but I will not need all the types. Just a few 5 or 6 functions. So I really don't intend to use the enum ( still trying to figure how to make it work for what I want to do).

All I want to do is that what ever value at *VAL determines which function to call in the function pointer array whose index should correspond to the value in the supposed enum.

For example,

`(access_data[*VAL])()`

From the code above, it will call dnt_cr function only if *VAL is 3 but what I want is to should call dnt_cr if *VAL is 225.

I hope this is clear...

Comment: Do you mean you want something like `int a[5] = {,,3,4,} to initialize only the third and fourth elements? (and yes, I know it isn't valid code, but its the idea i'm trying to clarify).

Comment: @WhozCraig please take a look at my edit above..I did explain further.

Comment: @WhozCraig looking at `int a[5] = {,,3,4,}. How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 5):

C99+:

```
int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
```

This syntax is also available as gcc extension in C89 mode.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I'm so unfamiliar with all of the C stuff that's diverted from C++. Some of it looks cool and some looks like it would be very redundant in a C++ environment.

Comment: @PaulA. well they say that they are ANSI compatible. You'd just have to remind them that ANSI has adopted C11 as its C standard and that they lack 23 years behind.

Comment: Please take a look at my edits in the question again. I did explain my intention.